# Django + Celery: ImportError: No module named project.urls

Tags: python, django, celery

When I start a worker using Django and Celery using this command (I execute the command within the `d` directory):

`celery -A e.project.celery:app worker -l info`

```
File "/Users/.../..../e/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-4.2.0-py2.7.egg/celery/loaders/base.py", line 108, in import_default_modules
    raise response

ImportError: No module named project.urls
```

I am using Django 1.11 and Celery 4.2 with Python 2.7.

Below is my project structure with the contents of some files that should be helpful for debugging.

Django structure:

```
d/
    __init__.py
    e/
        __init__.py
        core/
            __init__.py
            app1/
                 __init__.py
                 tasks.py
        project/ (project stuff)
            __init__.py
            celery.py
            settings.py
            urls.py
            context_processors.py
            wsgi.py
    manage.py
    setup.py
```

`settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'...',
'django_celery_results',
'django_celery_beat'
]


CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://foo:foo@127.0.0.1:6599/1'
CELERY_CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

`e/project/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from e.project.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app', )
```

`e/project/celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
import sys
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "e.project.settings")

app = Celery('e_tasks')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`d/e/core/app1/tasks.py`:

```
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def hello_world_task():
    print('Hello world')
```

My `manage.py` file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'e'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "e.project.settings")

try:
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
except ImportError:
    # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
    # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
    # exceptions on Python 2.
    try:
        import django
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        )
    raise
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Does `INSTALLED_APPS` contains `'project'`?

Comment: Nope, I never put `project ` in INSTALLED_APPS. My entire Django app works fine w/o it. Why would I have to put that there? Perhaps I'll make a different directory to story `celery.py` if that's the case.

Comment: @AAA you have strange structure of project. Do you have customizations in `manage.py`? `'...'` in INSTALLED_APPS - is your real code or you just abbreviated before pasting here?

Comment: `...` is abbreviation before pasting here.

I will copy and paste my `manage.py` file into the OP.

Comment: I just pasted my `manage.py` file. Could it be the `os.path.append` part?

Comment: Try `PYTHONPATH=$PWD/e celery -A e.project.celery:app worker -l info`

Comment: I see that you use `e.project.celery` and `e.project.settings`, but the error says something about not finding `project.urls` (no `e.` at the start). How did you define the `ROOT_URLCONF` setting?

Comment: @Ralf That was indeed the problem, oops! If you answer the question,  I will accept your answer and reward you the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the question, I see that you use `e.project.celery` and `e.project.settings` in your import statements, but the error says something about not finding `project.urls` (there is no `e.` at the start).

How did you define the `ROOT_URLCONF` setting? Maybe that is causing the problem.